# Why I am getting the error that file or directory not found although both are present in google drive and also in Colab Notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using the following command to run a python file. But I am getting the errors of file not found. Although I can see the files in Colab Notebooks and in Colab Notebook there is also one folder named InputData. How to fix this error? However when I use the following command t run heelo.py file it works fine.

```
`!python3 '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/3Band Graphics_modify.py'`

#ERROR
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/3Band_Graphics_modify.py", line 125, in <module>
main()
File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/3Band_Graphics_modify.py", line 20, in main
nsample = np.save("InputData/nsample.npy",nsample)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in save
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 541, in save
fid = open(file, "wb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'InputData/nsample.npy'`
```

Comment: In a jupyter cell, try running this command instead `%run "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/3Band Graphics_modify.py"`

Comment: Now i'm getting this error:      ERROR:root:File `'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/3Band Graphics_modify.py'` not found.

Comment: Have you mounted your Google Drive into your colab?

Comment: In 3Band_Graphics_modify.py should save some files in the folder InputData , that is also present in Colab Notebooks

Comment: Yes I used this from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Comment: Now, you need to change the working directory... use the following command `import os; os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks")`. Then, tell me the output of the following command `!ls`

Comment: 3Band_Graphics_modify.py         InputData    Untitled0.ipynb
 3DpbcL12W2.0n14437          KL_vs_E.py    Untitled1.ipynb
'Copy of Welcome To Colaboratory'       Result_2D    Untitled6.py
'Copy of Welcome To Colaboratory (1)'   single_3band2.py
 hello.py           Untitled                                                                                    it lists all files and folders

Comment: Now, run this command `%run "3Band_Graphics_modify.py"`

Comment: Yes now it works fine. Thanks. Can you please explain a bit that why my command is not working that I mentioned in the question?

Comment: I've explained it in an answer so it can be helpful for other people who don't read the comments. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was within the working directory. After mounting GoogleDrive, the default working directory is `/content/drive` which doesn't contain any of the user's files.

And to fix that, all you need to do is changing the working directory using the following command:

```
import os

os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks")
```

This will change the current working directory from `/content/drive` to `/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks` where the Original Poster has all the needed files.

Then, to run a python script in Jupyter Notebooks, you can use the magic command `%run`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!python3 './content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/3Band Graphics_modify.py'
```